# set up 2 networks card with different gateways

Tags: networking, netplan, routing

I have a VMs Ubuntu server 20.04 with two network cards, I would like to set up a different vlan with different gateway in each one. I made my routing table in the file yaml but when I assign gateway to each interface when I apply netplan I am getting the error: Conflicting default route declaration for ipv4

here is my yaml file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBBh5.png)

here is my rt_table file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0Y70.png)

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In later releases of netplan, the `gateway4` field is being deprecated altogether precisely because of this kind of confusion.

You should only include your default route for each interface under `routes` instead.  I see you are already doing this for one interface:

```
  routes:
    - to: 0.0.0.0/0
      via: 10.150.250.1
      table: 800
```

Note that `gateway4` is equivalent to setting a default route under `routes`, *except*, that you cannot declare a routing table when using `gateway4`!  This is why only one is allowed, because if you define `gateway4` twice you get incoherent routes in the default routing table.